# Combining storyboard with code

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

Is there a way to combine storyboard items for example views with swift code?
I have a setup like this:

```
- UIView
-- UIScrollview
--- UIView
---- UIImageView
---- UITextview
```

I have this set up in storyboard and I have used constraints on the imageview and textview. Can I modify for example the textview using code (like modifying its size or constraints)? How can I do that? Are object ids used for this purpose? If not, what are they used for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `IBOutlet`s to your constraints by <kbd>control</kbd> dragging from the constraints in the Document Outline view to the code.

[image: addContraintOutlet]

---

Then you can update the `constant` property of the constraint from your code.

[image: update constraint from code]

Answer (score 0):

Yes remaker you should be able to modify them no problem. It sounds like you need to set up your IBOutlet's though. If you are not familiar with them, what they do is create a reference to a variable you set in code. For example, if you are trying to modify your `UITextView`, you would need to create an outlet for it.

There are a couple different ways to do this, an easy way is to find the view in your storyboard, open the assistant editor (the button near the top right that looks like its wearing a suit) and while holding the option key click and drag on the view and drop it into your code that should have been brought up in the assistant editor. It will ask you to set a few properties and name the outlet, but then it will insert the outlet into your code. After the outlet has been setup, you should be able to modify the view by using the `@IBOutlet` that was created. Your's might end up looking something like this after inserted into the code `@IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!`